# Transcript show doesn't work

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm making a linked list structure with pharo smalltalk , and I'm trying to print my list to have an overview , I used 'Transcript show:' method but it doesn't work it prints "an Element" (the name of objects in the list) on the transcript , and when I use it separately on a workspace to print '3' or 'hello' for example it's works perfectly. I have read a lot of similar topics and it does not resolve my problem: 
here is my code :

```
    printList
     |current|
     current := Element newElement: first.
     [ current  == nil ] whileFalse: [ Transcript show: (current getValue); cr.
                                        current := current getNext ].
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: what is the result of `current getValue`? Maybe you forget to return the value in `getValue` method and so you are printing the `current` itself which prints "an Element"

Comment: alternatively, you may want to add a printOn: method which you can use to create a custom output, instead of "an Element" it could be "an Element(value) and then you can send the element itself to the transcript"

Comment: getValue return the right value when I do Transcript show: someList getFirst getValue.

Comment: how can I add a printOn: method ? sould I remove my printList method or I can keep it ?

Comment: since you are printing elements, the printOn: method should go in the Element class. and it would not replace printList in your list, but rather just allow you to write: Transcript show: current, and not have to worry about extracting the value manually. printList in your list class could of course be converted to printOn: too.

Comment: okay I see , I will try to do that and I will tell you if I managed to do it, thank you very much !

Comment: btw: this conversation looks more like general chat now, rather than directly commenting on the question itself. we may want to move this to the stackoverflow chat or even to #pharo on irc  on freenode

Comment: ah okay , no problem, I'm new in this forum .. so thank you !

Comment: i am quite new here too, so i just found out that stackoverflow will automatically suggest moving a conversation to chat when appropriate. (and also, that you need 20 points to join chat yourself). so don't worry and continue here if you have questions, or ask on irc.

Comment: Or just post an answer as opposed to making comments on the question. I would really appreciate it if you took the time to mark my answer as helpful - it would help my reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code is working and as it tries to print the element to the Transcript it calls Element>>asString. Since your object doesn't implement this method, it falls back to the inherited Object>>asString method which tries to be clever and uses the default pattern which generates 'an Element'.

The solution is simple - just implement the asString method yourself in your Element class:

```
asString
    ^'Hello I am an Element'
```

You can get smarter than this. You usually want to make the output uniquely identifiable. If your Element class has a 'name' instance variable you can use this for example:

```
asString
    ^(name ifNil: ['(empty)']), ' Element'
```

This will print something like:

> MyName Element

Comment: Also I recomment using 'Transcript crShow:' instead of 'Transcript show:'. This will print each output on its own line.